# how to request user permissions using facebook api in js?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

how to request user permissions using facebook api in js?
I want to let people login my site using facebook login. then I want to request facebook datas from the visitor. now I can get datas like this using js

```
FB.api('/100005658545226?fields=id,name,email') =>

{
    "id": "100005658545226",
    "name": "Mingfish Lin"
}
```

but there is no email info in the response json, so I want to send a request to ask user to authorize this email permission . how can I do this job in js? such as what does bellow.
[image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call the login method with a callback and an options object with an array as the scope property, such as:

```
FB.login(callback, {scope: ['email']});
```

More info at [Facebook Permissions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/)